# How many inclines are there in Pittsburgh?

Tags: pittsburgh

The **Monongahela Incline** can be reached by taking the metro to "Station Square" and walking to the bottom of the incline. https://monongahelaincline.com/

The **Duquesne Incline** can be reached by taking a bus or driving to the carpark at the bottom of the incline, http://www.duquesneincline.org/index.html

---

What about the **Knoxville Incline**, is it operational? Can we visit it like the other 2 more tourist-friendly incline? https://historicpittsburgh.org/islandora/object/pitt:MSP285.B022.F12.I02

From this list, it looks like the Knoxville incline isn't operational anymore but I still find a [Knoxville Incline Overlook Park](https://www.google.com/search?q=knoxville+incline+pittsburgh&biw=1600&bih=776&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=APwXEdfoD-L8kG9K6lrKdzVYxELQ_nlEpg%3A1680411005577&ei=fQkpZLXvIvSq5NoP24mE-AY&oq=kno&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWxvY2FsEAMYADIECCMQJzIHCAAQigUQQzIHCAAQigUQQzIHCAAQigUQQzIHCAAQigUQQzINCAAQigUQsQMQgwEQQzIICAAQgAQQsQMyEAgAEIAEEBQQhwIQsQMQgwEyEAgAEIAEEBQQhwIQsQMQgwEyBwgAEIoFEEM6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEIoFEIYDOggIABCKBRCRAjoNCAAQigUQsQMQgwEQCjoKCAAQgAQQFBCHAlC6BFjRB2CtFGgAcAB4AIABbIgBjQOSAQMyLjKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-local#rlfi=hd:;si:10210452045072924530,l,Chxrbm94dmlsbGUgaW5jbGluZSBwaXR0c2J1cmdoSJqM05aZqoCACFooEAEQAhgAGAEYAiIca25veHZpbGxlIGluY2xpbmUgcGl0dHNidXJnaJIBBHBhcmvgAQA,y,X3M3be6F0-0;mv:%5B%5B40.42353904519856,-79.98766284285281%5D,%5B40.4228427569171,-79.98924534617159%5D%5D) on Google maps. **Is the park accessible?** And a tour friendly park, e.g. take photos, view the scene, sit down and just drink/eat ice cream?

There are other inclines listed on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inclines_in_Pittsburgh but the bottom states

> This list is incomplete; you can help by adding missing items. (February 2011)

**Are there any other operational / disfunct incline in Pittsburgh not on the wikipedia list?**

Comment: is that the same as a funicular?

Comment: @njzk2 yes, they are funiculars.